# "A NNN REIT" or "an NNN REIT"

Tags: articles, vowels

I would think it's "a NNN REIT" in this case, despite the vowel sound, because this would typically be read as "a triple-net REIT" by those with domain knowledge. The person I consulted with said NNN might be read as the individual letters rather than as "triple-net". What should I go with here?

Comment: Easy - you use ‘a’ and your consultant uses ‘an’.

Answer (score 2):

Nouns that start with a consonant sound use the indefinite article *a*; those that start with a vowel sound use the indefinite article *an*.

In your case, you present an ambiguous situation because the pronunciation varies from person to person.

The only way around it (unless you have a house style guide that specifies usage) is to rephrase all sentences involved so that neither *a* nor *an* is used:

> This is a single NNN REIT.
>   This is one NNN REIT.
>   Consider this NNN REIT.
>   When investing, pick an appropriate NNN REIT.

I'm not familiar with how this term is used, but I'm sure I could come up with some way of phrasing any sentence that includes it in such a way that the indefinite article is be dropped.

It might not sound quite as natural as using either *a* or *an* with a given pronunciation, but it will sound more natural than using the wrong word with that pronunciation.